# Undefined value shows in the second dropdown value for multiple dropdown value in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, drop-down-menu, laravel-8

I want to make multiple dropdown using 1 table only. I don't get any error but when I select the first dropdown value, the second dropdown value shows `undefined` value. Which part did I missed or wrong?

**Controller:-**

```
public function index(Request $req)
{
    $shiftpattern = ShiftPattern::all();

    return view('admin.usershiftpattern',
        compact('shiftpattern'));
}

public function findSapCode(Request $request)
{
    $data=ShiftPattern::select('code','id')->where('id',$request->id)->take(100)->get();
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

**View:-**

```
<div class="col-md-3">
                            <select class="shiftPatternID" name="inputShiftPatternID" id="inputShiftPatternID" required style="width: 100%">
                                <option value="" hidden disabled selected>Please Select</option>
                                @foreach($shiftpattern as $singleshiftpattern)
                                    <option value="{{$singleshiftpattern->id}}">{{$singleshiftpattern->id}} - {{$singleshiftpattern->code}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <select class="sapCode" name="inputSapCode" id="inputSapCode" required style="width: 100%">
                                <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Please Select</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**Script inside view:-**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(document).on('change','.shiftPatternID',function(){

            var cat_id=$(this).val();
            var div=$(this).parent().parent().parent();
            var op=" ";

            $.ajax({
                type:'get',
                url:'{!!URL::to('findSapCode')!!}',
                data:{
                    'id':cat_id
                },
                success:function(data){
                    op+='<option value="0" selected disabled>Please Select</option>';
                    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                        op+='<option value="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].sapCode+'</option>';
                    }

                    div.find('.sapCode').html(" ");
                    div.find('.sapCode').append(op);
                },
                error:function(){

                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

undefined error is due accessing wrong key from `object`.You are accessing  `sapCode` but it doesn't exist in object so its throwing `undefined`.As per ajax response it should be `code` not `sapCode`

```
op+='<option value="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].code+'</option>';
```

Comment: Do you mean, i need to remove this line --> $(document).ready(function(){ ?

Comment: Still got the same issues, undefined value

Comment: check once inspect element of select and post what option value set

Comment: Sorry, i dont undesrtand? how sir?

Comment: using browser inspect element developer option .you can see by pressing f12

Comment: try removing  <option value="" hidden disabled selected>Please Select</option> and test .but i tried it works fine .still to check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233587/discussion-between-daisy-and-john-lobo).

Comment: sir... The second dropdown value is not save inside the database? it takes the first dropdown value. @John Lobo

Answer (score 1):

Please forgive me if I make any errors. My English is pretty basic.

Model get() function will rerun [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#collections) instance

## Controller

```
public function findSapCode(Request $request)
{
    return ShiftPattern::select('code','id')->where('id',$request->get(id))->take(100)->get()->toJSON();
}
```

You can via URL::to('findSapCode') to check the Collection content.

## Script inside view:-

```
$(document).on('change','.shiftPatternID',function(){

            var cat_id=$(this).val();
            var div=$(this).parent().parent().parent();
            var op=" ";

            $.ajax({
                type:'get',
                url:'{!!URL::to('findSapCode')!!}',
                data:{
                    'id':cat_id
                },
                success:function(data){
                    data.forEach(function (value, index) {
                        div.find('.sapCode').append('<option value="'+data.id+'">'+data.sapCode+'</option>');
                    });
                },
                error:function(){

                }
            });
        });
```

Use foreach() function to access every row data.

Comment: thanks @kliedo. Already got the answer! :D